# Adding cells based on another dropdown cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have two columns, the left column are numbers, and the right column is a dropdown. In the dropdown there will be 3 categories (undefined, cat1, cat2, cat3)

How can I add a cell into another cell, where the dropdown determines which cell to add the cell into.

Example:

```
10    cat2
2     cat1
22    cat2
```

Then in the cells below I'll have an overview added together:

```
undefined     0
cat1          2
cat2          32
cat3          0
```

Comment: What is the question here ? Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and a ask a question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How can I add a cell into an array(int only), using a dropdown is to determine which array to add the cell into.

Comment: Changed the wording and added the question in the comment into the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your numbers are in column A, your dropdown in column B and your category you want to sum for in D1, this is the formula

```
=sumif(B:B,D1,A:A)
```

Comment: Had a think about it, and what I am looking to do is build a counter based on a category being selected.

Comment: Then this formula can do it (fill A with 1), but if you only need to count you can use also: `=countif(B:B,D1)`  with column B the categories (your dropdown boxes) and D1 the category you want to count